# apex trigger to update a field in lead unexpected behavior

Tags: apex, trigger

my goal is to update custom field seller_id__c(if Account_id__c is 1122 then seller_id__c should update with 1122) in Lead object with custom field Account_id__c in Account whenever there is a new record/update in Account happens. My trigger behavior is little bit awkward can you please suggest changes where I am doing mistakes.

Note:Account__c is a lookup relationship from lead to account

```
Trigger Lead_Update on Account (after insert, after update) {

    set<Id> acctIds = new set<Id>();
    map<string, Account> mapAccount = new map<string, Account>();
    list<Lead> listLead = new list<Lead>();

    for(Account acct : trigger.new) {
        acctIds.add(acct.Id);
        mapAccount.put(acct.Id, acct);
    }

    listLead = [SELECT Name, Seller_id__c, Status, Account__c FROM Lead WHERE Account__c IN : acctIds];

    if(listLead.size() > 0) {
        for(Lead ldu : listLead) {
            ldu.Seller_id__c = mapAccount.get(ldu.Account__c).Account_ID__c;

        }
        update listLead;
        system.debug(listLead);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what mean *little bit awkward*?

Comment: why cant you use a formula field here if your only goal is to update the seller__c field with a value from the field in account?(If you want the user not to edit the field and the seller__c field always has the value from the field Account_ID__c in account)

Comment: It's updating seller_id__c only when we link both ways account to lead and lead to account. But my requirement is when we insert/update account then only it should update seller_id__c in lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Remove unwanted code in your trigger. Keep it simple.

```
trigger Lead_Update on Account (after insert, after update) {
    list<Lead> listLead = new list<Lead>();

    for(Lead ldu : [SELECT Id, Name, Seller_id__c, Status, Account__c FROM Lead WHERE Account__c IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()]) {
        ldu.Seller_id__c = Trigger.newMap.get(ldu.Account__c).Account_ID__c;
        listLead.add(ldu);
    }
    if(!listLead.isEmpty()){
        update listLead;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working Reshma we forget to add the lead records got the mistake.

Comment: @Laxman glad to help you. Please mark the answer so that it would be helpful to many others.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below piece of code

`Trigger.newMap` context variable is available in `after insert` and `after update` so you don't need to have any for loop for creating the map.

```
trigger Lead_Update on Account (after insert, after update) {
   if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
    list<Lead> updateLeadList = new list<Lead>();

    for(Lead ldu : [SELECT Name, Seller_id__c, Status, Account__c FROM Lead WHERE Account__c IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()]) {
        ldu.Seller_id__c = Trigger.newMap.get(ldu.Account__c).Account_ID__c;
        updateLeadList.add(ldu);
    }
    if(!updateLeadList.isEmpty())
        update updateLeadList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try with RCS provided piece of code

Comment: Not working RCS code

Comment: could you let us know what exactly is not working?

Comment: it's not updating seller_id__c field in leads

Comment: Have you checked the `debug log` why its not updating the field? Is there any specific `error message` that you encountered? Please check `FLS` as well.

Comment: We don't have any FLS on seller_id__c and account__id__c. While debugging the debug log showing 10|DEBUG|() which means it's not updating anything.

Comment: If I have not misunderstood the above comment then probably you need to give `Field Level Permission` for `Seller_Id__c`

Comment: Please see the updated code. Mark it as correct answer if it works